# mmap reading stale array of integers from an file

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

I'm trying to read matrix of integers from file using mmap. If I receive it as char pointer from mmap function, I see everything correct but if I use int pointer, it gives me stale data. **Problem with using char pointer is that I need to parse whole string using strtok or something else and get integers one by one.** My matrix size is going to be 4k * 4k hence making that many calls to sscanf and strtok is not efficient. Please look at the program and output

```
#define INTS 3 * 3

int main()
{

    FILE* in = fopen("int_file", "rb");
    int* ints = (int*)mmap(0, INTS * sizeof(int),
                      PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, fileno(in),0);
    fclose(in);
    for(int i = 0; i < INTS; ++i) { 
        std::cout << ints[i] << std::endl;
    }
    munmap(ints, INTS * sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Contents of int_file is

`510 20 30
40 50 60
100 200 10000`

Output

`540029237
857747506
808716848
540030240
822751286
84097028`

Comment: I think the ASCII value is getting printed.

Comment: storing it as `int *` is incorrect. Using `char *` and `strtok` and `atoi` would be best option available.

Comment: But I saw on various links on internet, storing it as int* works for people. I don't know what's the problem here

Comment: Reading it as `int *` is possible if the data in file is stored from `int array` or continuous memory through calloc. ie, creating array `int a[10];` and cast a to char pointer `char *cPtr = (char *) a` and storing it in file 10*sizeof(int) bytes. Reading back it as `int *` should work just fine. Is your case here similar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACSII value of the text is getting printed.

Your text seems like:

```
510 20 30...
```

From ASCII table (to explain what I want to tell):

```
No.       ASCII (hex)

Space ->   20
0     ->   30
1     ->   31
2     ->   32
3     ->   33
5     ->   35
```

`int` is `4` byte in size, so, taking first `4` bytes:

Converting to ASCII, `"510 "` gives `"35 31 30 20"` in memory which is `0x20303135` (`540029237` as decimal) for a little endian machine.
Similarly, next `4` bytes `"20 3"` gives `0x33203032`(`857747506` as decimal).
This is what you are getting.

You need to convert each ACSII to integer using atoi() or similar, in this case.

But you may store your integers as their binary value itself rather than keeping it as ASCII. The file will not be human readable but it will do your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Reading it as `int *` is possible if the data in file is stored from int array or continuous memory through calloc. **Writer** should look like,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int inst[] = {510, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 100, 200, 10000 };

#define INTS 3 * 3

int main()
{
        FILE* out = fopen("int_file", "wb");  // Error checks are needed
        char *ptr = (char *) inst;
        fwrite( ptr, sizeof( int ), INTS, out );
        fclose( out);
        return 0;
}
```

Then the **reader** can read using `mmap` like as it is in your code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

#define INTS 3 * 3

int main()
{

    FILE* in = fopen("int_file", "rb");    // Error checks are needed
    int* ints = (int*)mmap(0, INTS * sizeof(int),
                    PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, fileno(in),0);
    fclose(in);
    for(int i = 0; i < INTS; ++i) {
            std::cout << ints[i] << std::endl;
    }
    munmap(ints, INTS * sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

If not stored from array or continuous memory, then using `char *` and `strtok` and `atoi` is the best solution..

Comment: It still seems difficult even if used with strtok. If I use strtok on char* received from mmap function, it will lead to seg fault since Strtok modifies the input buffer. Do you think, if I make a copy of string received from mmap, I would still have performance of mmap. I don't know how does mmap helps you since there are so many things needed to parse string mapped in memory

Comment: Moreover, how do I copy since to allocate a buffer of size equal to mapped string, I need to know the mapped string size which is not possible.

Comment: As explained in answer, if int array is mapped to file and mapped back to application as int array, then strtok will not be necessary. This will be better when compared to strtok. Here, to maintain the number of elements in array, the first element of array can be used. Then, when you map array `3, 10239, 5762, 434`, then it means `3` is size and remaining 3 elements are actual data.

Comment: To get any more in-depth answers related to mapping array, please post it as separate question.

Comment: Input file is 4k * 4k float elements which I'm supposed to take and write do algo solution on that data hence that file is beyond my control and written manually probably but not through c++ program.

Comment: In that case, using strtok and atof is the only solution possible. Better post it as separate question as this question is changed now